# ElasticSearch + LogStash + docker-compose: simple logstash.conf without volume mount

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, logstash-configuration

Small question regarding ElasticSearch + LogStash + docker-compose, and the possibility to start LogStash with a configuration logstash.conf without volume mount please.

For testing purpose, I would like to start an ElasticSearch and a LogStash. The LogStash purpose is to forward logs to the ElasticSearch cluster.

Popular logstash.conf found on the web are like this:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch.mynetwork:9200"]
    index => "myapp"
  }
}
```

If I save this as a file, and mount it in my dockerfile, it works like a charm, very happy.

However, it requires to mount a file from the local system onto the container.

Since this configuration file is super simple, I was wondering if I could just pass the content of the config file as environment variable in the docker compose file.

Here is what I tried:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  elasticsearch:
    networks: ["mynetwork"]
    container_name: elasticsearch.mynetwork
    hostname: elasticsearch.mynetwork
    image: elasticsearch:8.6.0
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1

  logstash:
    networks: [ "mynetwork" ]
    container_name: logstash.mynetwork
    hostname: logstash.mynetwork
    image: logstash:8.6.0
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
      - 5044:5044
      - 5000:5000/tcp
      - 5000:5000/udp
    environment:
      LS_SETTINGS_DIR: input {  tcp {    port => 5000    codec => json  }}output {  elasticsearch {    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch.mynetwork:9200"]    index => "myapp"  }}
```

However, LogStash is not able to forward to Elastic.

May I ask what is the proper way to configure LogStash, so that it can take into account the conf file without mounting it as a volume please?

Thank you